# How to add +1 to win counter every time a win occurs?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add +1 to the win counter every time a win occurs but it doesn't work no matter what I try.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css">
<script src="myjavascript2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="center">
<button onclick="myFunction1()">Play</button>

<p id="rolled">You rolled:</p>
<p id="test"></p>



<p id="rolled1">Your opponent rolled:</p>
<p id="test1"></p>
<p id="test2"></p>
<p id="test3"></p>

<br><br><br>

<span>Wins:</span><span id="span1"></span><br>
<span>Losses:</span><span id="span2"></span><br>
<span>Draws:</span><span id="span3"></span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var things = [ 'rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];

function myFunction1() {

var random1 = Math.floor((Math.random()*things.length));
var random2 = Math.floor((Math.random()*things.length));

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=things[random1];
document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML=things[random2];
document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML='';
document.getElementById("test3").innerHTML='';

document.getElementById("span1").innerHTML=win;
document.getElementById("span2").innerHTML=loss;
document.getElementById("span3").innerHTML=draw;

if (random1 == random2) {

document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML="<h3>It's a draw.</h3>";
}   

else if (random1 == 0 && random2 == 2) {

document.getElementById("test3").innerHTML="You win!";
}

else if (random1 == 1 && random2 == 0) {

document.getElementById("test3").innerHTML="You win!";
}

else if (random1 == 2 && random2 == 1) {

document.getElementById("test3").innerHTML="You win!";
}

else if (random1 == 0 && random2 == 1) {

document.getElementById("test3").innerHTML="You lost!";
}

else if (random1 == 1 && random2 == 2) {

document.getElementById("test3").innerHTML="You lost!";
}

else if (random1 == 2 && random2 == 0) {

document.getElementById("test3").innerHTML="You lost!";
}



var test3 = document.getElementById("test3");
var win = 0;
var loss = 0;
var draw = 0;
```

Here is where I want to add +1 to the win counter every time a win occurs, but I can't get it to work. I have tried this:

```
if (test3.innerHTML == "You win!") {

document.getElementById("span1").innerHTML=win + 1;


}
```

This:

```
if (test3.innerHTML == "You win!") {

document.getElementById("span1").innerHTML=win++;


}
```

And this:

```
if (test3.innerHTML == "You win!") {

win = win + 1;


}

} //End of myFunction1
```

What am I doing wrong exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You did not declare the variable outside the function, Declare the `win` variable outside the function with `0` default value. eg:-

```
var win = 0;

function myFunction1() {
   if (test3.innerHTML == "You win!") {

   win = win + 1;
   ....
```

**UPDATE**
Here is the fixed version [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QQ7yK/)

Comment: So why do I have to declare the test3 variable inside the function? Cuz it didn't work when it was outside.

Comment: I am talking about declare the variable `win` outside the function not `test`, please make me correct If I am wrong.

Comment: it works even when you define the `test` outside the function, but you should get the `test`'s innerHTML on each click so you need write fetching text code inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Define var win=0; outside of your function, as it is now your win variable is being created in the function and dying at the end of the function.

Another thing that you can do is: inside the function add this at the top:

```
var win=parseInt(document.getElementById('span1').innerText);
```

Answer (score 0):

is `test3` defined?

```
if (test3.innerHTML == "You win!") {
}
```

if not, use

```
if (document.getElementById("test3").innerHTML == "You win!") {
}
```

Comment: it's defined above the win, loss, and draw variable.

Comment: Strangely enough changing it to if (document.getElementById("test3").innerHTML == "You win!") {
} made it work.. even tho test3 was defined?

Comment: I see. maybe you wrote if-statement before you defined `test3`?

Comment: test3 was defined outside the function, not sure why that mattered?

Comment: Maybe the function was called before? try debugging by tracing the value of `test3` to better understand the flow of your code.